# Reload private context from main context in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have an app in which I have created two private contexts from the main context using method

```
public func newPrivateContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
   let privateContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
   privateContext.parent = mainContext
   return privateContext
}
```

Now I have performed one operation with private context and save that context

```
privateContext.saveContext()
mainContext.undoContext()
```

How do I refresh or reload that second private context from the main context in iOS?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Siddharth

Answer (score 0):

Set your child contexts `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent:` to `true` if you support iOS 10 or above. Otherwise you'll have to monitor your main context `save` using `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` and merge the changes using `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:`. Ideally you'd use a combination of the two depending on whether the devices os supports it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i have concerned that if made any changes on that second private context will that override from main context or it will merge that

Comment: Merge - depending on your context mergePolicy. You can also get the inserted/deleted/updated object from the notification and compare with your second private context changes.